# AttributeError: class 'Test' object has no attribute 'A'

Tags: python

I am writing a testclass to test the functions of another one.When I try to compile the code I get the following error : "AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'A' " . Here is my code:

```
'''
\package 
Created on 23.04.2013

@author: kuiekejl
@see http://svnserv01/hf_programmierung/doku/dokumente/PythonCookbook    /PythonCookbook.pdf
@brief 
'''
import unittest
from math import sin
from math import pi
from src.parallelogram import Parallelogram

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def Setup(self):
        self.A= 3.00
        self.B=7.00
        self.Angle=pi/3

    def testparallelogram(self): 
        parallelogram= Parallelogram(self.A,self.B,self.Angle)

        testgetArea = self.A*self.B*sin(self.Angle)
        self.assertEqual(parallelogram.getArea,testgetArea)

        testgetOutline=2*(self.A+self.B)        
        self.assertEqual(parallelogram.getOutLine,testgetOutline)      

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I would appreciate any help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 6):

The setup method is named `setUp`, not `Setup`. Yours isn't being run.